# tkinter not working on a jupyter notebook, but working on terminal and an IDE

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am working on Ubuntu, and I am trying to use tkinter on a jupyter notebook but as soon as I try to import the module I get the following message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e89bfb5dd03b> in <module>
----> 1 import tkinter as tk

/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py in <module>
     34 import sys
     35 
---> 36 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     37 TclError = _tkinter.TclError
     38 from tkinter.constants import *

ImportError: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which is weird since when I tried to use `tkinter` on the terminal and everything seems to work fine.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I also tried to use tkinter on VS Code and it also run smoothly. It seems to only be making problems on jupyter.

Comment: you may have to register the ipython kernel for your jupyter notebook to run with the correct environment. In your environment, try: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"` (adjust as needed)

Comment: thankd for your response @warped. Shall I run this on my ubuntu terminal? or on the jupyter terminal?

Comment: run this from your terminal after you have activated the environment you want to run jupyter notebook in. Then you should be able to select the correct kernel once you have loaded your notebook

Comment: I received this error when runing on the terminal: `Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'`.

Comment: i am not an expert on ubuntu. would sudo work?

Comment: I could not, unfortunately, solve the problem. But I just installed anaconda and it works now fine. Alhough, I would like to understand what happened without anaconda! Thank you for your help @warped.